# React Put request with table refresh

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have written a form that toggles the value of a record when submitted.  I need the table to refresh after the data has updated on the DB, so the user doesn't have to manually refresh to view the updated info.  Currently, what I have written works, kind of...but it seems like the first time you run the update on a record, the refresh (which I can see happen) does not catch the changes, but if you try to toggle the value again, the change is reflected after each toggle/refresh.  Then if you select a new record it does the same thing.  I am wondering if my refresh is happening before the data has completely updated, and the refresh after the next toggle is catching the previous update, not the current one.  So I was wanting to find a way to rewrite my PUT request to only fire the refreshTable function after the record had successfully updated.

**FORM**

```
export function DeptStatusSwitch(props) {
    const { closeModal, refreshTable, selectedRecord, ltStatusUrl } = props;

    const { values, setValues } = FormFunctions(true);
    const classes = useStyles();
    const item = values; // used for easier referencing (matches table item)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedRecord !== null) {
            setValues({
                ...selectedRecord
        }); }
    }, [selectedRecord, setValues]);


// Edit Record
    function editRecordStatus() {
        axios.put(`${ltStatusUrl + (item.id)}`, {
            title: 'Success',
            body: 'The record had been successfully updated'
        });
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        editRecordStatus();
        closeModal();
        refreshTable();
    };

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
            <Grid container spacing={0} justifyContent='center'>
               <Typography>
                  Are you sure you want to {item.isArchived === 1 ? 'ACTIVATE' : 'DEACTIVATE'} this department?
               </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={0} justifyContent='center'>
            <Typography className={classes.boldItalic} >
                  {item.name}
               </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                    <Controls.Button
                        type='submit'
                        text='Confirm'
                        onClick={editRecordStatus}
                    />
                    <Controls.Button
                        text='Cancel'
                        color='default'
                        onClick={closeModal}
                    />
                </div>
            </Grid>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

I use the refreshTable function to increase my refreshKey, which is triggering the fetchData function, and causes the table data to reload.

**How I am Refreshing the Table**

```
  // Refresh Table
    const [refreshKey, setRefreshKey] = React.useState(1);
    const refreshTable = () => { setRefreshKey(refreshKey + 1); };


// Fetching Data
React.useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
    const res = await axios.get(ltReadUrl);
    setTableData( res.data );
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
  fetchData();
  }, [setTableData, setLoading, refreshKey]);
```

Can my PUT request be rewritten as an async command and refresh after a successful update (if so, how), or is it the way I am triggering the refresh using the refreshKey that is causing my issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making editRecordStatus async. Then after request completed, call refreshTable. Like this:

```
async function editRecordStatus() {
        await axios.put(`${ltStatusUrl + (item.id)}`, {
            title: 'Success',
            body: 'The record had been successfully updated'
        });
        refreshTable();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, but couldn't get it written properly using arrow syntax like I am used to using.